# Proof using Möbius transformation

Tags: complex-numbers

Let D be the open unit disc, and $f:D\to D$ an analitic function.

How can I prove that $|f'(0)|\le1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $R\in (0,1)$ we have by Cauchy's Integral formula: $$|f'(0)|=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R} \frac{f}{(z-0)^2} dz\right|\le \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\max_{|z|=R}|f|}{|z|^2}\le \frac{1}{R}.$$ But that means that $|f'(0)|\le \frac{1}{R}$ for every $R\in (0,1)$, so certainly $|f'(0)|\le 1$.

Comment: I knew I was forgetting something.